# How to decode this type of json in Python using json library?

Tags: python, json

I want to decode this json in python but i was unable to find any proper working docs.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-MiZDzE6eV_oy-k7liD7" : {
      "lat" : 22.992344005762106,
      "lon" : 88.39171958538499,
      "name" : "user1",
      "time" : "7:29:57,Time In,Thu Sep 02 2021 07:29:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
    },
    "-MiZeikP4SFbwAU2-ubt" : {
      "lat" : 22.992344005762106,
      "lon" : 88.39171958538499,
      "name" : "user2",
      "time" : "9:31:9,Time In,Thu Sep 02 2021 09:31:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
    }
  }
}
```

Like this
name = each name value from json 
lat = each lat value from json
and so on..

I have tried this far

```
import json
import requests

url = "someurl"
response = requests.get(url)
json = json.loads(response.text)
user = json["users"]
print(user["name"])
```

Comment: Please see my answer below, but I did want to take a second to point out that your variable `json` overwrites the module `json` you imported on line 1. This will cause you lots of confusion later on, better to just rename it. just calling it `json_` would be sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructuring JSON(which is what I think you mean instead of decode) is a a great candidate for [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

This can be done like so:

```
names = [user['name'] for user in json['user'].values()]
lat = [user['lat'] for user in json['user'].values()]
```

If you have many of these to do a normal loop may be your better option.

Bonus: requests will convert json for you. `json = response.json()`

Answer (score -1):

you just have to do:

```
import requests
url = "example.com"
data = requests.get(url).json()
# There are 2 Indexes in the JSON output,
# 1 Being -MiZDzE6eV_oy-k7liD7
# and the other being: -MiZeikP4SFbwAU2-ubt
ind2 = data["-MiZeikP4SFbwAU2-ubt"] # For the second index
ind1 = data["-MiZDzE6eV_oy-k7liD7"]
# Now we Parse what we need from the Seperate Indexes
user1 = ind1["name"]
user2 = ind2["name"]
print(user1)
print(user2)
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.